# Multiple Selects and a Join ..SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2
FROM table1
WHERE col3
IN(SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col4 IN(SELECT col4 FROM table4 WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'))
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6
ORDER BY table1.col1
```

I get a `ORA00933 error.SQL command not properly ended.` If I remove the join, the query works perfectly. But i need the join. The error is near the LIKE keyword. How can I solve it?

Comment: Try moving the WHERE statement after the JOIN, just before the ORDER BY. Don't think even Oracle supports a WHERE in the middle of a JOIN statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misplaced the `INNER JOIN`, it was located in your `WHERE` clause.

Note that you might want to adopt *some* formatting scheme for writing SQL Statements. It makes it much easier to spot these kind of errors.

```
SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2 
FROM   table1 
       INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6 
WHERE  col3 IN (
          SELECT col1 
          FROM table3 
          WHERE col4 IN (
             SELECT col4 
             FROM table4 
             WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'
          )
       ) 
ORDER BY table1.col1
```

Comment: is there any SQL editor freeware that can help format such queries?

Comment: Most likely there will be but I never found the need to actually search for one. I'm still not entirely settled on one specific style myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your join up ahead of your `WHERE` clause:

```
    SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.col1=table2.col6
    WHERE col3
    IN(SELECT col1 FROM table3 WHERE col4 IN(SELECT col4 FROM table4 WHERE col5 LIKE '%XYZ%'))
    ORDER BY table1.col1
```